Aligning equation number inside aligned
Hi I would like to have multiple multiline equations aligned at their equal sign, while keeping the style of the aligned for the multiline section. Further, the equation number should appear at the end of the last line of the multiline. The best I came up with so far is
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,english]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        f_1 ={}&
        \begin{aligned}[t]
            &  A + B \\
            &+ C + D
        \end{aligned} \\[2ex]
        f_2 ={}&
        \begin{aligned}[t]
            &  E + F \\
            &+ G + H
        \end{aligned}
    \end{align}
\end{document}

However, this will put the equation number, of course, on the first line, as the first line is the line of the align-environment. Obviously, I cannot put a \tag{\theequation} inside split and suppress the numbering of the align line with \notag. Another approach would be using split
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,english]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
  \begin{align}
    f_1 ={}&
    \begin{split}
        &  A + B \\
        &+ C + D
    \end{split} \\[2ex]
    f_2 ={}&
    \begin{split}
        &  E + F \\
        &+ G + H
    \end{split}
\end{align}
\end{document}

But everything inside split is treated as one block and this block is centered with the outside part i.e. the f_1 = and f_2, respectively. That is something I do not like. I want only the top line being vertically aligned with the equal sign.
Now, I also tried playing around with alginat etc. and different combinations of these environments.
If there is no way to get what I want its fine, then I will continue with the equation number on the first line, but I thought maybe I am making it far to complicated and there is actually an easy answer to this :)
Oh, and I load amsmath via mathtools.

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Oh yeah, sure sorry. Both codes should now be compilable.

The minimal class often causes unrelated complications, better use article

Use split, but in the proper way:
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
f_1 &= A + B \\
    &\hphantom{{}=A} + C + D \label{A}
\end{split}
\\[2ex]
\begin{split}
f_2 &= E + F \\
    &\hphantom{{}=E} + G + H \label{B}
\end{split}
\end{align}

\eqref{A} and \eqref{B}

\end{document}

Production note: I used twocolumn just to make a smaller picture.

If you want the number aligned with the last row, call
\usepackage[tbtags]{mathtools}


Aligning the number with the top line is out of question.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{2}
  f_1 & ={} && A + B \notag \\
      &     && + C + D \\
  f_2 & ={} && E + F \notag \\
      &     && + G + H
\end{alignat}
\end{document}



Great and many thanks, that works. As I expected, it is far more straightforward than I thought and made it sound. Interestingly, in my real document with longer equations this is centred slightly more to the right of the page than when using the nested align and aligned, even though the internal alignment is exactly the same. What is the LaTeX logic behind this?

Provide an example@Goroth

Please, avoid minimal which is not meant for code examples.

The desired formatting can be achieved with a single align environment if it's coupled with a pair of \notag instructions.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        f_1 &= A + B \notag \\
            &\quad + C + D  \\[2ex]
        f_2 &= E + F \notag \\
            &\quad + G + H
    \end{align}
\end{document}

